# Angular : run sub modules as independant app into a parent app

Tags: angularjs, nested, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

I am trying to run, N time the same Angular module independently into a "parent" Angular App.

Using ui-route and ui-route-extra, i can display N time the child app, but they do not run independently : they shared services as singletons (I need a unique service instance for each child module instance), and changing state (via state.go or ui-sref) into a particular instance, change the state into all the others.

I cant find any way to run these child modules as independant app into a container app...

EDIT :
I will give you some background to avoid XY problem.

To make it simple, i build a chat system. I have built a standalone chat Angular App, anyone can integrate into its website (as a widget). 
Now, i am trying to make an admin interface displaying all opened chat room. To avoid code duplication, i want to reuse the widget app into admin interface. 
The problem is to separate behavior for each room. I need multiples services instances, and state change should be applyed into specific room.

Comment: Would it work to export a class from your module and make N different instances of that class?

Comment: It depends on particular case if it can be done or not. I've haven't seen a real-world task where it would be necessary. Please, explain your situation in details with (simplified) code examples. It seems that you have XY problem that should be solved in conventional way. E.g. if you need multiple service instances, make a class a `factory` service and `new` it whenever needed.